# Creating a javascript variable from an array of elements

Tags: javascript, dom

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

returns an array of elements.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

returns a single element.

but for some reason,

```
var firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

returns 'undefined'. Strangely, global variables do not seem to have this problem.

```
firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

returns an element.

Comment: You're doing something wrong; please show a complete example.

Comment: There must be something peculiar about the environment you're doing this in because it works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cwUxL/.

Comment: Not your problem, but note that [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) doesn't return an array, it returns a _live_ NodeList. Which admittedly you access like an array, but because it is _live_ it will automatically update itself if matching elements are added or removed. (Just something that may bite you if you're not aware of it.)

Comment: @Adrian - Whether or not the variable is global doesn't necessarily change depending on whether it is declared or not. In the posted code, *firstDiv* is global in both cases (unless there is other code you aren't showing).

Comment: @RobG You're absolutely right. The problem was the difference between a variable expression and a variable declaration, not the difference between local and global variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073369/creating-a-javascript-variable-from-an-array-of-elements/8073406#8073406

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm still wrapping my head around the live thing. There's more information from MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName I'm still not clear on this: If I assign the live node list to a var - is that var also 'live'?

Comment: Yes. Your variable points to whatever `.getElementsByTagName()` returns, and what it returns is a live list. If your variable is a global it will hold the reference indefinitely. But the "live" aspect mostly only matters if you are looping through the list and inserting or deleting new elements, so don't stress about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` keyword is to blame. Note that this

```
var x = ...
```

is a variable *declaration* while this

```
x = ...
```

is an *expression statement*. Expression statement returns a value. Declarations do not. Declaration which contains initialization with some expression initializes the variable, but the value of the initializer does **not** become the value of the declaration (since declarations do not have a value).

All of these "return" undefined:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('div') 
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

All of these return something (an array of divs or the first div):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div') 
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
a = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
b = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

Comment: You're assuming he assigns the value of `var ...` to something. My psychic powers tell me he's running it in a console ;-)

Comment: True; I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Could you dumb it down for the retard over here? I don't get what you're saying ><

Comment: Are you saying the statement `var x = 'something'` in itself doesn't return anyting? As if the OP was trying to use it in an `if` statement or something?

Comment: OP did not explain what they meant by "return". My assumption is they were running these in a console. Note quotes around my use of "return" where I think the word isn't actually applicable.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thanks for clearing this up, your answer is spot on. I was indeed testing all of this in the console. 'Returned' isn't the correct terminology - but I don't know what is. This is a really interesting subtlety.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic powers tell me that your code is running before the browser parses the body.

Move the `<script>` block to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @SLaks - if that was the issue, then neither statement would "work". Declaring a variable doesn't change when the value is assigned.

Comment: @RobG is correct. The problem is easily reproducible: if you go to http://google.com and paste my code examples into your console, you should see the same results I had.